# Using spatial search in Solr utilizing Cassandra in DataStax Enterprise

Tags: xml, solr, cassandra, schema, datastax-enterprise

Good morning,

What I am trying to do is a spatial search on data which is stored within my Cassandra database and connected to Solr utilizing the DataStax Enterprise.

Some information....  I already have the database created and stored with data..  I have also already created a solr core and I can query data within my database using the Solr Admin.

At this point, I am at the step of altering my schema.xml so that my data can be read and spatial queries can be performed.

I have a few questions,

1) What variable type should I be using within Cassandra in order to be able to have my latitude and longitude points read correctly by cassandra?

This is what I have now -- an example input --

-- my latlng (longitude latitude points) is stored as a varchar variable in cassandra.

```
insert into device(id, location) VALUES('test','45.17614,-93.87341');
```

--still getting the same result when running:

```
"error": {
    "msg": "The field location does not support spatial filtering",
    "trace": "org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: The field location does not support spatial filtering
    "code": 500
```

}

2)  Here is my current schema.xml ---- does it look correct to you?

*Not sure if I have dynamicField in the right place..... (tried in fields section too)

This is the query I'm using in solr admin.... also tried on terminal

`{!geofilt pt=45.15,-93.85 sfield=location d=5}`    ---- on admin

`SELECT * FROM device WHERE solr_query='{!geofilt sfield=location pt=45.15,-93.85 d=5}' limit 10;`    ----- on terminal

My keyspace was made like this:

CREATE KEYSPACE device WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'Solr':1};

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
    <types>
        <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
        <fieldType class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"     name="coord"/>
    </types>
    <fields>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="id" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
        <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="location" stored="true" type="coord"/>
        <dynamicField name="*_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have tried dynamiceField under the field line within fields as well to no avail....

Comment: Your reported data doesn't make sense: you created a table named "pois" and then query a table named "mylocation"; your query result sample doesn't match the schema.xml... please post clear, consistent data and then we'll try to help.

Comment: I apologize, I have edited all of the information now.

Answer (score 2):

1. As per the DSE doc, LatLonType maps to Cassandra text or varchar column types.

Check the Solr wiki for some Solr examples:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch

2. Your schema looks fine, at a quick glance.

The error message refers to a different field name ("mylocation") than the Solr schema you specified ("location").

Comment: I have edited my original question to include the data within my database, in varchar for the actual points.  Does that data appear to be input correctly Jack?

Comment: by the way, that was my mistake, I am specifying mylocation in the schema now -- just hadn't put the up to date schema up..... I'm still having the same error appear